# unexpectedly found nil when refreshing UI of presentingViewController within dismissViewController callback

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm trying to reload the UI of a view (MyMatches) thats presenting another view (BuyView). When BuyView is dismissed, I want to reload all of the views of MyMatches. However, when I try to do this within the completion of "dismissViewController", I run into an "unexpectedly found nil" error on the line "let mmvc = self.presentingViewController? as! MyMatchesViewController". Does anyone know why this happens, or if there's an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Code posted below is found within BuyViewController:

```
func itemBought() {
    print("Confirm tapped!")
    BoughtController.globalController.sendSellerNotification(seller, match: match)
    BoughtController.globalController.updateBuyer(self.item, buyer: LocalUser.user, match: self.match)
    BoughtController.globalController.updateMarket(self.item, match: self.match)
    BoughtController.globalController.updateSeller(self.item, seller: seller, soldPrice: self.match.matchedPrice)


    self.cancel = false

    if self.fromInfo == true {

        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    else {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            let mmvc = self.presentingViewController as! MyMatchesViewController
            mmvc.setupMatchesScrollContent()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` block runs after the view controller has been dismissed and thus `self.presentingViewController` has changed?  Perhaps.  Safer to use:

```
else {
   let mmvc = self.presentingViewController as! MyMatchesViewController              
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
     mmvc.setupMatchesScrollContent()
   }
}
```

where you 'capture' `mmvc` before using it in the trailing closure.